# Backing up DVDs on computer and change the audio tracks from 192 to 384 kbps

Tags: conversion, bitrate

I'm backing up my dvd's and I can decide what Bitrate the output file (*.avi) will have. I can choose between AC3 (384 kbps, 48000 hz) and MP3 (64 - 384 kbps, 24000 - 48000 hz).

In that program it is easier for me to click AC3 (I cannot change anything there) than clicking in the MP3 options since most of my dvd's have multiple languages and I have to choose for each language again and again what bitrate / quality they will have.

However, I just checked that the files on my dvd have only 192 kbps so 384 would be much more. Is that bad or won't I even notice the difference when using 384 kbps?

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to upsample the bitrate. Your files have already lost the info from being compressed to 192. It looks to me as if the AC3 is going to give you a similar if not slightly more consistant result to the MP3. Seeing as this option is also easier to do using the program you mentioned... **Go with the AC3**